# Scala merge two maps with different value type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Given two maps

```
  val m1 = Map("a" -> "a")
  val m2 = Map("a" -> 1)
```

as a result of merging those two, I would like to get

```
Map("a" -> ("a",1))
```

I tried cats semigroupal for this and it pretty much did the job, but I had to create instance for semigroupal by my self, like this

```
Semigroupal.catsSemigroupalForMap[String]
```

and then merge them with `product` method. What do I need to do to not create it manually? E.g. merging two options is straightforward

```
val noneInt: Option[Int] = None
val some3: Option[Int] = Some(3)
Semigroupal[Option].product(noneInt, some)
```

I would like to achieve a similar code to merge two maps, but when defining

```
Semigroupal[Map]
```

The compiler cannot find any implicity for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tupled` seems to do the trick:

```scala
@ val mapA = Map(1 -> 2)
mapA: Map[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

@ val mapB = Map(1 -> "b")
mapB: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "b")

@ (mapA, mapB).tupled
res4: Map[Int, (Int, String)] = Map(1 -> (2, "b"))
```

And it compiles generically:

```scala
@ def mergeMaps[A, B, C](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, C]): Map[A, (B, C)] = (m1, m2).tupled
defined function mergeMaps

@ mergeMaps(mapA, mapB)
res6: Map[Int, (Int, String)] = Map(1 -> (2, "b"))
```

It destroys keys that are not in both maps:

```scala
@ val m1 = Map("a" -> "foo", "b" -> "bar")
m1: Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "foo", "b" -> "bar")

@ val m2 = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3)
m2: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3)

@ mergeMaps(m1, m2)
res9: Map[String, (String, Int)] = Map("a" -> ("foo", 1))
```

Comment: I was sure it could be simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good use case for [`Align`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Align.html)

```scala
import cats.data.Ior
import cats.syntax.all._

def combineMaps[K, A, B](m1: Map[K, A], m2: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A, B)] =
  m1.align(m2).collect {
    case (key, Ior.Both(a, b)) => key -> (a, b)
  }
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
val m1 = Map("a" -> "foo", "b" -> "bar")
val m2 = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3)

val result = combineMaps(m1, m2)
// result: Map[String, (String, Int)] = Map("a" -> ("foo", 1))
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/JzbOAUk9T76LPjUPCDzCow)*.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Scala may serve you as well. To merge multiple Maps you need to:

- transform input Maps into sequences of tuples and append everything
- groupBy to get into a Map again. This will accumulate the values from the same key.
- pick whatever you want from the output Map

```scala
def merge(first: Map[String, Int], rest: Map[String, Int]*): Map[String, Seq[Int]] =
  rest
    .iterator
    .foldLeft(first.toSeq) { _ ++ _ } 
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(pairs => pairs.map(_._2))

val m1 = Map("b" -> 2)
val m2 = Map("a" -> 1)
val m3 = Map("a" -> 1)

merge(m1, m2, m3)
merge(m1, m2)
merge(m1)
```